# ajax.dll not working in iis 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

ajax dll working in IIS 6,but not working IIS 7.
ajax dll need to install any frameworks in server?

web config in system.web tag

```
<assemblies>
<add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=2.0.50727.1433, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
</assemblies>
<httpHandlers>
<add verb="POST,GET" path="ajax/*.ashx" type="Ajax.PageHandlerFactory, Ajax" />
</httpHandlers>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 <system.webServer>    
 <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <modules>
    <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </modules>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated" />

    <add verb="POST,GET" name="Ajax" path="ajax/*.ashx" type="Ajax.PageHandlerFactory, Ajax" />
    <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </handlers>
  </system.webServer>


   <system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="POST,GET"  path="ajax/*.ashx" type="Ajax.PageHandlerFactory, Ajax"/>
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are using Integrated .NET mode in IIS 7, then the httpHanders config need to change. Refer to [this](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Oct/10/HttpModule-and-HttpHandler-sections-in-IIS-7-webconfig-files)