# Ajax.dll is not working on a site hosted in IIS 7.5 Windows Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, ajax, windows, iis-7.5

So I am tasked to look into an ajax method not working on a site that is hosted on windows server 2008 and running on IIS 7.5. Upon researching this, found out that the Ajax.dll is not loading at all in IIS 7.5 and after making some web config changes in the system.webserver section, I am still having issues. As per one of the posts online, someone was able to resolve this issue by removing the Web Server role from the server and added it again, the explanation they provided was after adding it back, it did bring some missing components that helped fix the issue. I could try doing this but one thing I am not so sure is there are currently a handful of sites hosted on IIS 7.5. If I remove this role, would they all go away? 
[image]

Thats what I am worried about to have to go back once I remove and add this role and bring those sites into IIS again. Please advise!

This is the error I am seeing on the page.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, getting rid of the Ajax and bringing jQuery to do the validation that the site was doing with the Ajax methods.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "EditTerritoryArea.aspx/CheckValue",
    data: JSON.stringify({ territoryID: _territoryID, code: box, value: value }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.d != null) // error calling server
        {
            txt.value = "";
            txt.focus();
            alert("A problem occurred while tying to communicate with the server.\nPlease try again in a few moments.");
            return;
        }
    });
```

Once confirmed this was doing what the site was intending to with the old Ajax methods, i removed all the Ajax references from the application.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the below code in your site web.confifg file which is causing this error message:

```
<system.webserver>
    <validation validateintegratedmodeconfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
        <add name="ScriptModule" precondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
  <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx" />
  <add verb="POST,GET" path="ajax/*.ashx" type="Ajax.PageHandlerFactory, Ajax" />
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" precondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" precondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="ScriptResource" precondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </handlers>
</system.webserver>
```

this change does not affect other site settings.

[ajax.dll not working in iis 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489193/ajax-dll-not-working-in-iis-7)

For your information Support for Windows Server 2008 and 2008 R2 has ended. you could try to upgrade your OS with the latest available operating system.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4456235/end-of-support-for-windows-server-2008-and-windows-server-2008-r2

Comment: Hi Jalpa, I did try the solution that you have proposed above but that didn't help either. One thing I am doing rather is getting rid of the Ajax methods and using jQuery, as I have been trying to resolve this for the past couple days but not getting anywhere.

Comment: @bladerunner could you please provide the sample code to reproduce the issue. and which ajax you are trying to change with the jquery.

Comment: Yes sure. Basically, it was this line: var response = AjaxMethods.CheckValue(_territoryID, box, value); and in the codebehind, it was using the Ajax Utility i believe the version was 1.1 to register the dlls like in the code below. Ajax.Utility.RegisterTypeForAjax(typeof(AjaxMethods)); The same thing was running fine on the site hosted on IIS 6 but when this site got moved to IIS 7.5, this script stopped running. Instead of reinventing the wheel, I decided to stop using Ajax as its not supported by Microsoft anymore, so instead replaced this with jquery ajax call. I am going to post that here.

Answer (score 0):

if you have ashx files with code that are compiled into javascript using the Ajax.PageHandlerFactory, and you have a setting like this in web.congif:

```
 <system.web>
   <httpHandlers>
  <add verb="POST,GET" path="ajax/*.ashx" type="Ajax.PageHandlerFactory, Ajax" />
</httpHandlers>
```

</system.web>

and your application is not creating the wanted JS files, check how your application pool is defined, if possible, put the application pool on Classic Mode, that will fix your code